# Linear-gradient does not show the correct color on Safari

Tags: html, css, safari, linear-gradients

I have this `<div>` with a simple css:

```css
.mapTop {
  z-index: 12;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding-left: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 96px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(45,59,78,0), #fff);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
body {
  background: #F4F5F6;
}
```

```html
<div class="mapTop">
</div>
```

In every other browser it looks like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/394Pt.png

But in safari it looks like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/IUYaC.png

Why is that?

Comment: Rgba is transparet? If yes better rgba (0,0,0,0) maybe is this the problem.

Answer (score 2):

According to what I've read on CSS-Tricks, Safari interprets transparent in gradient backgrounds as "transparent black". Here is the link: https://css-tricks.com/thing-know-gradients-transparent-black/

So, just use:

```
.mapTop {
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, from(rgba(255,255,255,0)), to(#fff));
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(255,255,255,0), #fff);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(255,255,255,0), #fff);
}
```

I've also auto-prefixed it so it's compatible with all browsers (except IE)

Comment: I also changed the background image from `background-image: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(255,255,255,0), #fff);` to `background-image: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(244,245,246,0), #fff);`